# C arithmetic precedence

Tags: c, arithmetic-expressions

I stumbled upon a question about arithmetic precedence in a test and I cannot wrap my head at all around its answer.

```c
float x = 5 % 3 * + 2 - 4.5 / 5 * 2 + 2;
```

My "understanding" right now is that multiplication must take place first before division and modulus, yet when I try using that approach, the answer is 6.55 instead of 4.20. I tried playing around with the expression (adding brackets here and there), and it turns out that 5 % 3 takes place first before everything else. I just don't understand why since, according to the precedence table I was provided, that shouldn't be the case. Could someone clear this up for me?

Comment: How would it work? You have `* +` and in between there is nothing to operate on. Someone please help me understand.

Comment: When you have operator of same precedence, the one comes first will be processed first.

Comment: @Shiv, that + is a unary operator on the 2 that follows.

Comment: @sh1 saved me. I knew that I am stupid and here comes proof.

Comment: I already figured I was

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to the [documentation here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

The precedence of multiplication, division and remainder operators are higher than those of sum and subtraction.

When multiplication, division or remainder operators go one after another, then they are *left-associated*, meaning they will be executed one by one in the given order.

In your example `5 % 3` will be performed first, then the multiplication (by whatever number there is), then the division `4.5 / 5`, then multiplication of the result by 2, and only after all that will the sum and subtraction be performed.

Answer (score 2):

Your C code:

```
x = 5 % 3 * + 2 - 4.5 / 5 * 2 + 2;
```

First, unary plus and unary minus has the highest precedence:

```
x = 5 % 3 * (+ 2) - 4.5 / 5 * 2 + 2;
```

Second, multiplication, division, and remainder have the same precedence, associated from left to right:

```
x = ((5 % 3) * (+ 2)) - ((4.5 / 5) * 2) + 2;
```

Last, addition and subtraction have the same precedence, associated from left to right:

```
x = ((((5 % 3) * (+ 2)) - ((4.5 / 5) * 2)) + 2);
```

Now we evaluate the expression:

```
x = (((2 * (+ 2)) - ((4.5 / 5) * 2)) + 2);
x = (((2 * 2) - ((4.5 / 5) * 2)) + 2);
x = ((4 - ((4.5 / 5) * 2)) + 2);
x = ((4 - (0.9 * 2)) + 2);
x = ((4 - 1.8) + 2);
x = (2.2 + 2);
x = 4.2;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can refers this link for more detail
http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm